# Fresh rails 6 app won't deploy on heroku due to 'error Command "webpack" not found'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack

I just created a new rails 6 app and getting the 'error Command "webpack" not found' message when i try to push to Heroku for the first time. I tried everything:
- regenerating the bins(including webpacker)
- adding nodeJS and Ruby to Heroku
Nothing works, i still get the same error message. Does anyone have any clue? I also want to precise that I've made sure i applied all the solutions presented in the questions looking like mine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to run `npm install` or `yarn install` on the server.

Whenever a node module like `webpack` says it "can't be found", this usually means it's not installed yet.